# How i use if condition with pluploadQueue

Tags: jquery

i have this code

```
("#uploadContainer").pluploadQueue({
  // General settings
  runtimes : 'gears,html5,flash,silverlight,browserplus',
  url : '{$upSet.handler}',
  max_file_size : '{$upSet.maxFilesize}mb',
  chunk_size : '1mb',
  unique_names : false,
  prevent_duplicates: true,             
  // Specify what files to browse for
  filters : [
        { title : "Files", extensions : "{$upSet.allowedFileTypes}" }
    ],
  filters: {
        min_img_resolution: 8000000 // 1MP = 1 million pixels
    },
  // Flash settings
  flash_swf_url : '{$baseURL}/assets/plupload-2.1.2/js/Moxie.swf',              
  // Silverlight settings
  silverlight_xap_url : '{$baseURL}/assets/plupload-2.1.2/js/Moxie.xap'
                        });
```

I need to put if condition before second filter to choose different minimum resolution. How i can do this?

Answer (score 1):

You can't inside of the uploader's settings. You would need to do this outside:

```
var min_img_resolution = 8000000; // default

if (whatever) {
    // change default if condition is met
    min_img_resolution = 4000000;
}

("#uploadContainer").pluploadQueue({
    runtimes : 'gears,html5,flash,silverlight,browserplus',
    url : '{$upSet.handler}',
    max_file_size : '{$upSet.maxFilesize}mb',
    chunk_size : '1mb',
    unique_names : false,
    prevent_duplicates: true,             
    filters : [
        { title : "Files", extensions : "{$upSet.allowedFileTypes}" }
    ],
    filters: {
        min_img_resolution: min_img_resolution // add variable here
    },
    flash_swf_url : '{$baseURL}/assets/plupload-2.1.2/js/Moxie.swf',              
    silverlight_xap_url : '{$baseURL}/assets/plupload-2.1.2/js/Moxie.xap'
});
```

Comment: THX PaparazzoKid but if i need to put if condition before filters it self in which to execute filter or not

Comment: i need to ask him if extension is (....) get filter for resolution and else if extension is (.....) don't use filter

Comment: @HamzaDarwesh: your question asked **"put if condition before second filter to choose different minimum resolution"**. I haven't put one before the filter becuase you cannot, but my method DOES allow you to choose a different minimum resolution as you asked.

Comment: my if condition depend on the extension of file type so i should wait to know what the file extension is then i use if condition