# how i can use if condition with pluploadQueue

Tags: jquery

i have this code

```
$("#uploadContainer").pluploadQueue({
    // General settings
    runtimes : 'gears,html5,flash,silverlight,browserplus',
    url : '{$upSet.handler}',
    max_file_size : '{$upSet.maxFilesize}mb',
    chunk_size : '1mb',
    unique_names : false,
    prevent_duplicates: true,               
    // Specify what files to browse for
    filters : [
        { title : "Files", extensions : "{$upSet.allowedFileTypes}" }
    ],
    filters: {
        min_img_resolution: 8000000 // 1MP = 1 million pixels
    },
    // Flash settings
    flash_swf_url : '{$baseURL}/assets/plupload-2.1.2/js/Moxie.swf',                
    // Silverlight settings
    silverlight_xap_url : '{$baseURL}/assets/plupload-2.1.2/js/Moxie.xap'
});
```

i need to put if condition depend on file type extension to use resolution or not how i can do this ?

Comment: Hamza, you **CANNOT** ask the same question twice. You accepted my answer on the same question only an hour ago and now you ask the same question again. If you weren't happy with my answer, then you shouldn't have accepted it and waited patiently for somebody else to help.

Answer (score 2):

You can always check before wath file type end after that sen value.

```
var useResolution = false;

if(fileExtention == [sonthing]) {
   useResolution = true;
}
```

Them you simply pass the value of useResolution into pluploadQueue({})

Hope this helps.

/Zorken17

Comment: This is what I suggested to him in my answer here, but he/she didn't like it for some reason: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/33544924/how-i-use-if-condition-with-pluploadqueue

Comment: I saw your answer and voted on it